# Garbage Collector Gen2 and Asp.net web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory, garbage-collection

> NET Garbage Collect is a generational collector. 
>   
>  NET Garbage Collect has 3 generations: generation 0, generation 1 and
>   generation 2.
>  Well tunes tuned app, most objects have to die in Gen0.

I have a doubt about what kind of object can be promoted to Gen2 in a Asp.net web app. 
Only object referenced in static field? What else can be promoted do Gen2 beside large objects?

Comment: All objects from Gen1 which are alive after collection of 1 generation are promoted to Gen2.

Comment: I know, but the point not clear for me is: during a short web request (a call to action in mvc)  what can be  promoted Gen 1 and then Gen2? My opinion is every objects instantiated during the execution of the action if not referenced in static field should never be promoted Gen1 or Gen2 But maybe I'm wrong and I would listen other opinions.

Comment: Not only static objects. There can be objects which live during application lifetime (service or repository object). And when Gen 0 or Gen 1  is full then these objects are promoted to the next generation.

Comment: Why service class or repository class should be promoted to Gen1 or Gen2? Is not clear to me... unless they are referenced in static class' variables (made available by singleton class or resolved using a DI container with application scoped lifetime)

Comment: @GhiniAntonio any object will get promoted to the next generation if it was in use during GC. GC's don't only happen between requests, the server could be in the middle of processing a long request and the GC could happen twice, that would make any objects tracked by local variables that are still in scope to go to Gen 2.

Comment: This could be an acceptable if you post this answer I will accept it